# Can patent technology be accesed by someone with teck knowledge?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, patent-services, patentscope, security

I am thinking about applying for a patent, If my accounts are not secure when I purchase a patent, Can the technology be accessed and potentially make security issues worse by using the technology against me? If so, are there ways to get help creating a security related patent or does it have to be 100% created by the person applying for the patent?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking about purchasing someone else’s patent or inventing something? How do you think owning intellectual property affects your security ?

Comment: If you want to file your own patent, then I strongly recommend consulting with a patent attorney who will be able to answer your questions without public disclosure.

Answer (score 1):

To answer one clear aspect of the question - an inventor can have others help with developing their invention. If the other people make a conceptual contribution to something that ends up being claimed they are a co-inventor. Otherwise they are helping with the invention and reduction to practice but are not co-inventors.

Via suitable agreement they can asssign ahead of time any inventorship rights to you. Of course you also need a confidential agreement with them before disclosing your invention.

To answer what might be another part of the question - patents once issued are publicly available no need for any technology to access the information.